# Unable to draw in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In the draw method of a CCLayer subclass I am trying to draw 2 pixels/points, on the line x=150 where y=239 or 240.

Changing the value of x doesn't affect/fix the problem.

This is the code I'm using:

```
glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);  
for (int i = 239; i < 241;  i++) {
    ccDrawPoint(CGPointMake(150, i));
}
```

what happens is that there is a point on y=239 and 24***1***.
This only happens on line y=240, which happens to be half of 480, the screen's height.

If I don't use a for loop and do 2 ccDrawPoints then it still doesn't work properly.

However if I draw a line over/intercepting y=240 the line does not have a break in it, so it's not just that y=240 is always black.

Comment: The `for` loop you posted draws 2 pixels, in the first sentence you say you want to draw 3 pixels. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Sorry just a typo, you see later on in my question I say 2 points, 239 and 240.